# disconnect wallets programatically from the frontend side

Tags: wallet, frontend

is there any way to disconnect a wallet from the frontend? If not, why?

```
walletProvider.disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
How are you doing the wallet connection? I'd recomment to take a look at this library `@polkadot-onboard` ([link on github](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-onboard/blob/main/README.md)).

> @polkadot-onboard provides a set of packages for developers to easily onboard and add different type of polkadot wallets to their dapps. It provides a universal interface for working with different type of wallets (e.g. Injected-wallets, Wallet-Connect, hardware-wallets).

[Here is an example of the connect()](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-onboard/blob/main/examples/react-headless/src/components/Wallet.tsx#LL40C9-L40C32). For the disconnect would be similar, and delete if you are storing the state of the account:

```
await wallet.disconnect();
```

Comment: it's actually empty for injected providers 
  https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-onboard/blob/b07e1cce7e40c95f127a69459250d72d191ea39b/packages/injected-wallets/src/injectedWallets.ts#L49